# Base64 decode error from .net string

Tags: java, base64

I'm trying to decode this base64 string that comes from a c# rest service.

> bABnLrav1BTJgKonT4u288arWYhfyPbHrmb2vq27ZlguHztSBD05AV3JBpJ6rlY8lyb70IOicJ7Twpi2UH1mqS7Hmk8NF/kWrRi/fZAPRsY8LwIE+ifn7Rm4r/ddiJqbrfs4d8QQiSOapwPoNbLgkOOBgs6DTzWTdvgN61VHC4LimXM3/CRlcMQ2L1CDeBvCatcuGtGcV8I87s7rQp0KggYUIZUYudjcBoPEFdZ2WBdJgLfsrisezrRYtd1NFs3q8YYyTbZfNUwLS8/JPCUD88Qrp5yp47yb0uz38Cgga97JK9mhWpxBdPX/c2eLSseESFL06vbIR40cscY0qlwhZA==

```
Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE))
```

And throws this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 0
```

What's wrong with the way I'm decoding it?

Comment: Why do you have a C# tag if you are coding in Java?

Comment: Are you sure `UTF_16LE` is the right format?

Comment: Yes, I can decode same string in python using UTF_16LE

Answer (score 0):

If you have an illegal character in the text, Base64.getDecoder() will throw an error. You could try Base64.getMimeDecoder() instead to ignore illegal characters.

Either way there are a number of online sites where you can check the validity of the base 64 text outside of your software (if you search for base64 encode decode you'll find a few you can use) in case the text isn't encoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The base64 string is fine and decodes to:

```
6C 00 67 2E B6 AF D4 14 C9 80 AA 27 4F 8B B6 F3
C6 AB 59 88 5F C8 F6 C7 AE 66 F6 BE AD BB 66 58
2E 1F 3B 52 04 3D 39 01 5D C9 06 92 7A AE 56 3C
97 26 FB D0 83 A2 70 9E D3 C2 98 B6 50 7D 66 A9
2E C7 9A 4F 0D 17 F9 16 AD 18 BF 7D 90 0F 46 C6
3C 2F 02 04 FA 27 E7 ED 19 B8 AF F7 5D 88 9A 9B
AD FB 38 77 C4 10 89 23 9A A7 03 E8 35 B2 E0 90
E3 81 82 CE 83 4F 35 93 76 F8 0D EB 55 47 0B 82
E2 99 73 37 FC 24 65 70 C4 36 2F 50 83 78 1B C2
6A D7 2E 1A D1 9C 57 C2 3C EE CE EB 42 9D 0A 82
06 14 21 95 18 B9 D8 DC 06 83 C4 15 D6 76 58 17
49 80 B7 EC AE 2B 1E CE B4 58 B5 DD 4D 16 CD EA
F1 86 32 4D B6 5F 35 4C 0B 4B CF C9 3C 25 03 F3
C4 2B A7 9C A9 E3 BC 9B D2 EC F7 F0 28 20 6B DE
C9 2B D9 A1 5A 9C 41 74 F5 FF 73 67 8B 4A C7 84
48 52 F4 EA F6 C8 47 8D 1C B1 C6 34 AA 5C 21 64
```

However, you should decode it as plain ascii, not as unicode.